# Insert @Html.TextAreaFor onclick of a button (jQuery) OR using AJX.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an edit form with `@Html.TextAreaFor` controls. I need to have a link 'Add New' which will insert a new `@Html.TextAreaFor` control at the end of the current display. Should it be `@Html.TextArea` control? If so, how should I fetch the information from newly created controls when I submit the form to save it to the DB?

```
@model ResourceTemplate
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ResourceTemplate</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResourcesLabel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResourcesLabel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResourcesLabel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (Model.Resources.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resources, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Resources.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Resources[i].Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 80, @rows = 50 } })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Resources[i].Uri, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 80, @rows = 50 } })
                </div>
            }
        </div>
     }
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextAreaFor` helper generates a `<textarea>` HTML element with the specified property as the name attribute value. 
Assuming its a new resource object you are trying to add you can follow this to generate a new resource input:

```
<div id="resourcesContainer" class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resources, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Resources.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Resources[i].Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 80, @rows = 50 } })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Resources[i].Uri, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 80, @rows = 50 } })
                </div>
            }

            <button type="button" id="btnAddResource">Add resource</button>

        </div>

<script>
$('#btnAddResource').on('click', function() {
    var container = $('#resourcesContainer');
    var index = container.children('div').length;
    var resourceText = $('<textarea>', { name: "Resources[" + index + "].Text"});
    var resourceUri = $('<textarea>', { name: "Resources[" + index + "].Uri"});
    container.append(
       $('<div>', { class="col-md-10" }).append(resourceText).append(resourceUri)
    );
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on comment, depending on how your partial is being rendered, you need to bind your button click event to the addResource function. This way its bound directly on the element markup but you can find an alternate way to bind it unobtrusively depending on your implementation.

```
<button type="button" onclick="addResource();">Add resource</button>

<script>
function addResource() {
    var container = $('#resourcesContainer');
    var index = container.children('div').length;
    var resourceText = $('<textarea>', { name: "Resources[" + index + "].Text"});
    var resourceUri = $('<textarea>', { name: "Resources[" + index + "].Uri"});
    container.append(
       $('<div>', { class="col-md-10" }).append(resourceText).append(resourceUri)
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @user11103429 Without seeing more of your particular implementation, I'd say you can wrap this in a function which the button can call. See edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! Have a great day!